# Apache web server problems on MacOS Mojave

Tags: macos, apache, macos-mojave

I have migrated to a new webhost that has MacOS Mojave installed. My previous installation used El Capitan (or maybe it was Yosemite) and worked perfectly. Previously, I had everything set up using Mac Server. However, as you may already know, over the last few OS "upgrades," Apple has reduced Server to the point that it now worse than useless. It no longer controls web hosting or anything else you might want to do. So I have been trying to use ApacheGUI.  After mucking around in httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf, my website is now responding on port 8080. Previously, my installation of Apache Tomcat used port 8080, but because I don't need Tomcat, this is really a non-issue. The problem is that the MacOS Server webpage ("Welcome to macOS Server") responds on port 80. I can't figure out how this is possible. I have copied my entire website to both /Library/WebServer/Documents (the document root specified in httpd.conf) and /Users/UserName/Website/website/com (the document root specified in httpd-vhosts.conf).

Any assistance would be appreciated. I have a working knowledge of how to get around in terminal and nano, but I don't know much about setting up a webserver manually thanks to my decade+ reliance on the now-deprecated MacOS Server.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, did you get it worked out?

Comment: Yes, I eventually got it working by mostly trial and error. I went through both httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf and removed any lines that referenced Apache Tomcat and changed any "8080" to "80." My website started responding normally after that. I'm not sure if that was the best way to do it, but I really had no other choice. Very disappointed I did not get a single response on here.